# Cloning an org for a divestiture at a customer

Tags: org

Does anyone know of a way to take an existing org and clone it to a new instance? We have a customer that is spinning off a division and would like the exact same SFDC setup but in a separate org that will be owned by the new legal entity. The customer would clone the org, delete all data not related to the divested division and then transfer ownership to them.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted, so other users can see there is a valid answer to your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce offers migration to other instances (mainly for the purpose of relocating an instance if customers want to transfer the instance to EU for example). In this process the original instance is set to read only while the data is being transferred. Afterwards the old instance is removed and the new one is activated.

However I'm pretty sure Salesforce will also be open to offer the pretty similar process of copying an instance as it is basically omitting the last step. There are some limitations to size of the org, etc. as well as some prerequisites. To start this process and get all the information needed you have to contact your account executive.